# A Circle of numbers

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

Just saw a Circle of numbers on my Whats App message (source not listed) which is as following

> Arrange numbers 1 to 32 in a circle such that any two adjacent
> (neighboring) numbers add up to a perfect square (like 1,4,9,16 etc). No
> number can be repeated.

Without programing you can try that and get an answer.

There is a question on this site

[Fourteen numbers around a circle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75846/fourteen-numbers-around-a-circle)

That puts 14 numbers around a circle where either the sum or the absolute difference between the neigboring numbers is a Prime number

**Here is my question**

> Can you put numbers 1 to 32 (without repeating any number) in a circle such that the sum of the
> neighboring numbers is a Prime Number?

So if any three numbers (clockwise or anti clockwise) are a,b and c then a+b and b+c must be a Prime. and so on.

You can either answer my question OR both the WhatsApp and my question together.

There may be more than one answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

> Clockwise ordered (or anti-clockwise ordered, if you prefer)
>  32, 11, 30, 13, 28, 15, 26, 17, 24, 19, 22, 21, 20, 23, 18, 25, 16, 27, 14, 29, 12, 31, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5, 8, 9

Strategy

> I focused on a set of twin primes and saw that I could start with a large even number and a small odd number and decrease the even number by 2 each alternate step while increasing the alternate odd number.
>  Starting with the large even number at 32, this would allow me to catch every number greater than or equal to the small odd number.
>  {41, 43} is the first twin prime pair above 32, so I started with this, making the first small odd number equal to 11 and so it catches every number above 11.
>  Then I just had to arrange the remaining numbers below 11 in a appropriate manner which wasn't too difficult on its own.

Comment: As long as the math checks out, I'm pretty sure the "anticlockwise ordered" version should work too :-)

Comment: @Bass haha, yes, that is a good point actually.

Comment: See you had the same base idea..

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT: This answer is wrong, I misunderstood the question***

Your question:

> 32 30 28 26 31 24 22 20 18 16 14 12 10 3 8 1 4 2 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29

Method:

> I realized that all the odd numbers (and all the even numbers) can be easily arranged such that the difference is always two. So I wrote two sequences 32, 30, 28... 6, 4, 2 and 1, 3, 5, 7... 25, 27, 29. Then I joined them removing 3,1 and 31 and placed them in three positions that fit. These positions were find by trial and errors.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. 32+30 , must add up to a Prime for example.

Comment: so of the numbers are a  b  c  d   e   f   g   etc  then  a+b  b+c  c+d  d+e  e+f  f+g  etc must be Prime numbers

Comment: @drd Sorry I though the difference must be a prime numbe

Comment: No issues. I think there could be several answers but I only got 1 without programming

Answer (score 0):

My strategy

> Start with a twin prime close to 33 : 29,31
>  Create the longest sequence with those, add the remaining numbers
>  1 28 3 26 5 24 7 22 9 *20* 11 18 13 16 15 14 17 12 19 *10* 21 8 23 6 25 4 27 2 29 30 31 *32*
>  Only 32 causes problems see where it can be swapped: with 20, 10 and 4
>  Of those 10 fits between 31 and 1 for the answer:
>   1 28 3 26 5 24 7 22 9 20 11 18 13 16 15 14 17 12 19 32 21 8 23 6 25 4 27 2 29 30 31 10